# Redirect in CreateView Django doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hi I try to make a blog using CBV. I want after create a new post in post_form.html the CreateView will redirect to the new post_detail I just made. So I was search on gg and try both get_success_url and redirect_field_name. But it still had error Page not found [image]. Because of that I really don't know the new post was created or not. Can someone check it for me.

Views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    form_class = forms.Post_form
    model = models.Post
    #redirect_field_name = 'mlog/post_detail.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk,})
```

urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>/',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
path('post/new/',views.PostCreateView.as_view(),name='post_new'),
path('post/<int:pk>/edit/',views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name='post_edit'),
path('post/<int:pk>/remove/',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='post_remove'),
path('dratf/',views.DraftListView.as_view(),name='post_draft_list'),
```

Comment: The error is not in the success url, but the `method=...` of the `<form>`. Can you please share the template `<form>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *not* the success URL, it is the method to which the form posts. You should make a POST request to the `post_new` view. Your `<form>` should thus specify:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'post_new' %}">
    …
</form>
```